# Inserting data from fetch into a HTML div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem getting data from my fetch response into a div. The data comes into the console just fine, but I can't get it to update the div.

```html
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="phand">
            <button id="deal" class="btn">Deal!</button>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'blackjack/play.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
(function () {


    function deal() {
        fetch('/deal')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            var card1Rank = data[0];
            var card1Suit = data[1];
            var card2Rank = data[2];
            var card2Suit = data[3];
            $("#phand").append('<acidjs-xdeck-card rank=' + card1Rank + 'suit=' + card1Suit + '></acidjs-xdeck-card>');

        });
    };

    $('#deal').on('click', function() {
        deal();
    });



}());
```

I want the javascript to insert the response from the fetch request into the "phand" element on the page, I can see the data coming through in the console, but it doesn't alter the contents of the page.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something but I think you need an additional import in the header part. According to this http://experiments.wemakesites.net/x-deck-html5-web-component.html .`<link rel="import" href="AcidJs.XDeck/classes/XDeck.html" />`

Comment: Yeah I've got that on the actual page, I just removed it to make it easier to follow. The problem is that the javascript doesn't insert anything into the html on the page at all, even if I change it to something arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to convert data to string with JSON.stringify() , try to append like

```
$("#phand").append('<acidjs-xdeck-card rank=' + JSON.stringify(card1Rank) + 'suit=' + JSON.stringify(card1Suit) + '></acidjs-xdeck-card>');
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had the "phand" div inside another "wrapper" div.
I changed the js to:

```js
$('#wrapper').find('#phand').append('<acidjs-xdeck-card rank=' + JSON.stringify(card1Rank) + 'suit=' + JSON.stringify(card1Suit) + '></acidjs-xdeck-card>');
```

and it worked as expected.